# How to check for a value in a string using a foreach loop

Tags: php

This might be a simple solution, however I am not able to come up with it, therefore any help is welcome.

I have a shopping basket so customers can add different items for it (as normal)
On some of these Items there are conditions and when added to the basket I'd like to show them up, however I have it setup so it checks for the value, but it only takes the value from the last added item.

Have the following

```
public function get_contents() {
$items = array();

        foreach($this->items as $tmpItem) {
            $item = null;
            $item['Condition']  = $this->Conditions[$tmpItem];
            $items[]          = $item;
        }
        return $items;
    }


    foreach($this->items as $item) {
        if(strstr($this->Conditions[$item], 'no') ==!false) {
            $this->Conditions = 'no';
            $item['Condition']      = $this->Conditions;
        } else  
            $this->Conditions = 'yes';
            $item['Condition']      = $this->Conditions;
```

What I would like to do is if any of these items contain the condition 'no'

```
  $this->Conditions = 'no';
  $item['Condition']      = $this->Conditions;
```

However it only takes the value of the last added item
Any help welcome

Comment: Does your $this->items contains all items in cart ?

Comment: @Sunil Thank you for looking, yes I think it does

Comment: and after the foreach what does $this->items prints ? does it contains "Condition" in each item or only the last one ?

Comment: Only the last one

Comment: then i think the problem in the definition of the item arrays, have you checked that $item in the loop in a simple array and not an object ?

Comment: I think you are right, however I'm not sure how to check that. Could you point me in the right direction please

Comment: can you update your question and add complete function or script here ?

Comment: @SunilVerma I want to find out if any of the items added have the value 'no' if any have then do something. Thanks for looking

Comment: in your method there is a line foreach($this->items as $tmpItem) { but then you have used $items but never updated it in the $this->items variable ?

Comment: I not sure how to do that. Is it something like $this->items['Condition'] to catch the array? I am really sorry, to keep asking this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132910/discussion-between-sunil-verma-and-ria).

Answer (score 1):

You are over riding the array element

```
foreach($this->items as $item) {
       if(strstr($this->Conditions[$item], 'no') ==!false){
       $this->Conditions = 'no';
       $item[]      = $this->Conditions;
       }
       else{   
       $this->Conditions = 'yes';
       $item[]      = $this->Conditions;
       }
}
```

Comment: also if you need item with no tag you could try `$item[$this->Conditions[$item]]      = 'no'`